# Why does the function append the txt file and not overwrite when the opening mode is "w'?

Tags: python, loops, file-io

I was following a tutorial that creates a function to create 20 txt files and add the multiplication tables from 1 to 20 in them. Here is the code-

```
#Create tables from 1 to 20 in different files 

for i in range(1,21):
    with open(f"table_{i}.txt","w") as f:
        for j in range(1,11):
            f.write(f"{i} x {j} = {i*j}\n")
```

This code does the job but I am not sure why does it append to the file and not overwrite it when it is open in "w"/writing mode?

Comment: How do you know that the files are appended to?

Comment: Are you questioning why doesn't every call to `f.write()` replace the existing contents of the file?

Comment: In the first run of the first loop, the file is created and it enters the second loop- which writes the multiplications one at a time. But because it is opened in 'w' mode, shouldn't it overwrite the last line in each iteration?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, shouldn't it overwrite in each iteration and I should end up with just the last one line because the mode is 'w'?

Comment: The file is truncated once (on open I believe), wouldn't be a great API if you couldn't write to a file multiple times

Comment: No, your 20 files should contain 10 lines each.

Comment: Append means that python will keep pre-existing content. Then you can write sad much as you want until the file is closed.

Comment: @quamrana Yes, the files do contain 10 lines each. But from what I learned, when we use the writing mode, the file pointer is at the beginning of the file and it overwrites whatever is written there with each call of the write() function. So, why doesn't it overwrite the files?

Comment: What I am saying is if you manually created these files with 1MB of random contents, and then ran your program, it would overwrite the files with 10 lines each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right when you use 'w' then it overwrites and does not append but here it is not appending. 
The concept of appending and overwriting comes into play when you open the file again but here we are not opening the file again but just writing in the opened file. 
Let me explain by an example:

```
for i in range(1,21):
    for j in range(1,11):
        with open(f"table_{i}.txt","w") as f:
            f.write(f"{i} x {j} = {i*j}\n")
```

try to run this code, it will give you 20 files as before but this time every file just had just a single column say *10 x 10 = 100* like this only because here we are opening the file after every line so every time we open, *'w'* overwrites the old data.

 
Hope it helps:)